# Remove all logs when using pandas_gbq on jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, google-bigquery, jupyter

Is it possible to remove all logs when using pandas_gbq on jupyter?

example:

```
sql = """
SELECT country_name, alpha_2_code
FROM [bigquery-public-data:utility_us.country_code_iso]
WHERE alpha_2_code LIKE 'Z%'
"""
for i in range(10):
    df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(
        sql,
        project_id=project_id,
        # Set the dialect to "legacy" to use legacy SQL syntax. As of
        # pandas-gbq version 0.10.0, the default dialect is "standard".
        dialect="legacy",
    )
```

outcome:

```
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.08rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.06rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  8.72rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  6.15rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.24rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  8.40rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.27rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.18rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.55rows/s]
Downloading: 100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  3.26rows/s]
```

I want the outcome to be nothing.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not logs, I also thought that for some time, but after playing around with the `logging` library and not being able to remove the message, which is the one recommended for the documentation to [handle log verbosity](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#adjusting-log-vebosity), with no success.

I jumped to the [code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py) and realized that there was a `progress_bar_type` parameter at the `pandas_gbq.read_gbq()` [function](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L823) that must be set to `None` in order to dismiss the message that you want to remove. [See the options.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L942)

So when you are calling the function it should look something like this:

```
pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, dialect="legacy", progress_bar_type=None)
```